# hapi validation for joi and send all error

Tags: javascript, validation, hapi

I am using joi for validating request 
like

> lastName: Joi.string().trim().min(3).optional().error(new Error('Please enter valid name')),
>
> email: Joi.string().email().required().lowercase().error(new Error('Please enter valid Email ID')),

it is working fine and i am also able to send error using failAction but if both validation fails it only send the first failed

like if you enter  lastName as h , and email as S@@com so it send only first error i.e "Please enter valid name" but I want response containing both error

I also try to use failAction but after failing fist validator it ignore all other validator any suggestion how can i get the required result

Answer (score 1):

> set `abortEarly: false`  in server setting by default it is true

```
server.connection({
    routes: {
        validate: {
            options: {
                abortEarly: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Check here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.0.4/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback)

Comment: it work but if you have custom error  i.e. error(new Error('Please enter valid Email ID')) it will throw those error first without all error